# Proper way to mock up nhibernate getNamedQuery for unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nhibernate

I have a named query set up to call a stored procedure against my Oracle DB:

```
<sql-query name="GetClientRegCode">
{ call get_registration_code(:in_param1, :in_param2, :in_param3) }
```

I call it in my code like this:

```
var regCodeData = _sessionManager.GetSession().GetNamedQuery("GetClientRegCode")
                            .SetParameter("in_param1", p1)
                            .SetParameter("in_param2", p2)
                            .SetParameter("in_param3", p3)
                            .List<object[]>()
                            .ToList();
```

I have been able to mock my session manager `GetSession()`. How do I go about mocking the NamedQuery GetClientRegCode?

Answer (score 0):

Simply don't. Write integration tests against your data access layer. In "higher" layers, fake/mock/stub your data access layer instead.

[Don't Mock What You Don't Own](https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=don%27t%20mock%20what%20you%20don%27t%20own)